# Incorrect conversion from double to long

Tags: java, android, long-integer, type-conversion, epoch

I have the following code:

`Double.valueOf(defaultValue.toString()).longValue()`

I'm using this line to parse the `defaultValue` of a TimePicker I've created for Android. I'm setting the default value for this (in my `PreferenceScreen` xml) to be `1483318800000`. For some reason, it starts off in scientific notation: `1.48331876E12` and then after running through the code above: `1483318760000`. It ends up being off. I need it to be correct since this is a timestamp in milliseconds. I'm shooting for 8pm--but I can only ever get it to be 7:59pm (since after the conversion, it's off).

If I do `Long.parseLong(defaultValue.toString())` then I'll get a `NumberFormatException` since it's in scientific notation.

How can I guarantee a *"good"* conversion?

**Edit:** The conversion code is the first line of code I'm showing above. I'm setting the default value like so:

```
    <TimePreference
            android:defaultValue="1483318830000"
            android:key="settings_night_mode_start_time"
            android:title="@string/settings_night_mode_start" />
```

Then it gets passed into [this function](https://github.com/Nxt3/IO_Classic_WatchFace/blob/night-mode/wear/src/main/java/io/nxt3/ioclassic/config/TimePreference.java#L78).

Comment: Fix the place which converts 1483318800000 to 1.48331876E12, because that part does it badly. The correct value should be 1.4833188E12.

Comment: show the conversation code to 1.48331876E12

Comment: Which type has `defaultValue` got?

Comment: I've updated the OP to show everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rustot's answer, I found out that [there is an issue with `Preferences` in Android regarding parsing the default values.](https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/30/beware-of-preference-default-values-in-xml/)

The fix was to set the default value with a string resource instead of the `long` value I was giving it.

`<string name="settings_night_mode_default_start_time" translatable="false">1483318830000</string>`

```
    <TimePreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_night_mode_default_start_time"
            android:key="settings_night_mode_start_time"
            android:title="@string/settings_night_mode_start" />
```

This works as expected. :)

Answer (score 3):

In some place before your code this value was already converted to Float (not Double) and then back to string.

```
System.out.println(Float.valueOf("1483318800000"));
```

1.48331876E12

Comment: Seems like it might be a problem with Android then. Setting the default value in a `Preference` xml of that length might auto-convert to a float. Thanks!

Comment: [Turns out I was right.](https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/30/beware-of-preference-default-values-in-xml/). Thanks to you, I've found a solution. I appreciate it!